# How to get object and save it to a new one

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson

I'm trying to build a webmap using Leaflet. My data are stored in a zipped shapefile, so I'm using the [shapefile-js](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/shapefile-js), which allows me to load and use the data. My program loads the zipped shapfile and adds the content to a geoJson object.
The next big thing: I want to grap the geoJson object to visualize the data in a table view using for example [datatables.net](http://datatables.net/) or [json Table](http://6edesign.github.io/JSONTable/index.html).

Firstly find some code below:

```
var m = L.map('map', {
        center : [51.3, 10.3],
        zoom : 6,
        minZoom : 6,
        maxZoom : 10
    });
var geo = L.geoJson({
        features : []
    }, {
        onEachFeature : function (feature, layer) {
            layer.on({
                click : displayInfos
            });
            layer.bindLabel(layer.feature.properties.GEN, {
                direction : 'auto'
            });

        },
        style : style,
    }).addTo(m);

// add the shapefile to the geojson object `geo`
shp('zipped_shapefile.zip').then(function (data) {
    geo.addData(data);
});
```

Now I have some questions about it:

**1.)** As already said, now I want to access the data as a (geo)json object. Using Chrome's developer tools, I ask for the 'geo'object and I get the following output:

> e {options: Object, _layers: Object, _initHooksCalled: true, _leaflet_id: 22, _map: e…}

Here is the question of why: Why is this not already a FeatureCollection type? This is only the case, if I use `geo.toGeoJSON();` , where geo is the L.geoJson object (check code above).

**2.)** I've tried to solve the problem with a workaround. So...using the developer console I type

```
> geo2 = geo.toGeoJSON();
```

and I get the following result:

> Object {type: "FeatureCollection", features: Array[412]}

This is exactly, what I want to have, isn't it? It's a json object... In my opinion, I only have to add this line at the end of my code (see the big code-block), but by doing it, I only get an empty FeatureCollection object.

```
> geo2  
Object {type: "FeatureCollection", features: Array[0]}
```

I need to know, how I can store the geo-object (from whatever reason the geo-object is not accessible as a json object (question 1)) as a json object (question 2). As previously mentioned: it works by using the console, but not by placing the lines in my code :-/
Any help is mich appreciated :)

Comment: Any ideas of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide an example in [jsfiddle]?  or a link to your site?